# Insert a Monogame view inside MvvmCross monodroid Activity

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin, mvvmcross, monogame

I'm trying to build a Monogame view inside a RelativeLayout from my MvvmCross monodroid Activity view.

An android Activity inherits from Microsoft.Xna.Framework.AndroidGameActivity to be able to run a Monogame inside a RelativeLayout (working).

My MvvmCross Activity inherits from MvxBindingActivityView(working).

So, I need a way to run the game and bind some datas within the same activity.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Loosely speaking, you can translate any Activity to an MvxActivity by inheriting some interfaces and by then cutting and pasting a small amount of code which does the basic loading and assignation of the ViewModel.

e.g. see the `#Region` and `IMvxAndroidView<TViewModel>` added to make [MvxActivityView.cs](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/vnext/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid/Views/MvxActivityView.cs) from a normal `Activity`.

e.g. it's the same region and interface used for adapting a specialised Activity like Google's `MapActivity` into [MvxMapActivityView.cs](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/vnext/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid.Maps/MvxMapActivityView.cs)

At this level, the Activity/View has a `ViewModel` which can be used in C# code, but has no clever xml inflation - it has no clever `Binding` support.

Code can be written at this level - I've shipped apps without binding - but many users prefer to add DataBinding too...

---

To add this DataBinding support, you need to add a bit more code which provides BindingInflate, storage of bindings, disposal of bindings, etc.

e.g. a raw `MvxActivityView` is extended using the `IMvxBindingActivity` interface and a #region like: [MvxBindingActivityView.cs](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/vnext/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid/Views/MvxBindingActivityView.cs%20sds)

e.g. `MvxMapActivityView` is extended using the same region and interface: [MvxBindingMapActivityView.cs](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/vnext/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid.Maps/MvxBindingMapActivityView.cs)

---

So to extend your the custom `AndroidGameActivity`:

1. Inherit from `AndroidGameActivity` to get `ViewModelOwningGameActivity<T>` and cut and paste the `IMvxAndroidView<TViewModel>` interface and `#region` from `MvxActivityView<T>` to provide the ViewModel methods, fields and properties.

Then assuming you want binding:

1. Inherit from `ViewModelOwningGameActivity<T>` to get `BindingGameActivity<T>` and cut and paste the `IMvxBindingActivity` and `#region` from `MvxBindingActivityView<T>` to get the binding methods

---

For specialist Activities you may want to add more - e.g. you may could add some custom helper methods for the MapActivity to plot points and lines, or for GameActivity to do *whatever games do*... but this is up to individual implementations.

---

Sorry about the cut and paste of code required in adapting Activities - I have tried to keep this to a minimum. However, writing Mvx is the one time so far that I've really wanted Multiple Inheritance or Mixins in C#

Comment: I cloned MvxActivityView to MvxGameActivityView and changed inheritance from Activity to AndroidGameActivity. Then I clone MvxBindingActivityView to MvxBindingGameActivityView and changed inheritance from MvxActivityView to MvxGameActivityView. It is working for now with my quick tests. Many thanks.