# MvvmCross - MonoGame

Tags: data-binding, mvvmcross, monogame

I'm trying to build a MonoGame view inside MvvmCross on Android,iOS and WP8. On Windows side it's relatively easy to use dependency properties as a binding target, but how can I achieve a cross platform data binding solution that I can use on all platform?

Answer (score 1):

This was covered in a previous MvvmCross version - see [Insert a Monogame view inside MvvmCross monodroid Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13201174/insert-a-monogame-view-inside-mvvmcross-monodroid-activity)

The technical details have changes a bit since that post, but the core of the advice remains the same - **use inheritance to add data-binding**.

For example, if you want to adapt a `FooActivity` or `FooViewController` base class so that it can be used for MvvmCross data-binding, then you need to:

- inherit from `FooActivity` to provide `EventSourceFooActivity` - to do this you need to add event notifications like those shown in [MvxEventSourceFragmentActivity.cs](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/v3/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid.Fragging/MvxEventSourceFragmentActivity.cs)
- inherit from `EventSourceFooActivity` to provide `BindingFooActivity` - to do this you need to add all the members like `DataContext` from [MvxFragmentActivity.cs](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/v3/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid.Fragging/MvxFragmentActivity.cs)

The process for Touch/iOS is very similar, but with iOS specific events and members. Take a look at any of the `Mvx*ViewController` classes to see what is involved.

This technique is also discussed in: [Integrating Google Mobile Analytics with MVVMCross](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14518876/integrating-google-mobile-analytics-with-mvvmcross)

Comment: When you get this working, I'd love to if the results were shared back to the community - also very interested to see how MonoGame and Mvvm might be combined together :)

Comment: my big question is if i can use this technique to add GameComponent the ability to have bindable properties.. to use them as every day ui elements. (and ofc create one unified GameComponent for all the platforms? or do i need to create platform specific components(ios/android/wp8/win8)?)
*btw atm i dont see how its doable with the solution you described... but ofc i might be wrong.

Comment: I have MonoGame working with the Xaml version using Prism for Mvvm. Also Farseer for Physics. You can even have your MonoGame sprites interact with your Xaml elements.