# Place a monogame view a inside mvvmcross window

Tags: mvvmcross, monogame

Microsoft has some examples of XNA within a winform [here](http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/winforms_series_1)

Has anyone put a DirectX Monogame window in an mvvmcross layout?
[The first of the Questions that relate to this say](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17316092/mvvmcross-monogame)

> "On Windows side it's relatively easy to use dependency properties as
>   a binding target"

I haven't even started with mvvmcross and I'm still new to monogame, though ive played with XNA a lot so that sentence doesn't quite make sense to me, If someone could point me to any kind of tutorial that explains that it would help a lot.

Comment: Why does the sentence not make any sense? Have you even tried to create an `Activity` implementation using `AndroidGameActivity` instead of `Activity`. The source code for MvvmCross is on GitHub it should be fairly easy to find out how `MvxActivity` is implemented.

Comment: **I haven't even started with mvvmcross and I'm still new to monogame** I was asking if anyone had tried it before so I could see how it was done