# ActionBarSherlock with latest MVVMCross

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, xamarin.android, xamarin, mvvmcross

Does anyone have a sample how to use ActionBarSherlock with latest MVVMCross?

There's Roosmaa / MvvmCross.ActionBarSherlock but it doesn't work with latest MVVMCross and I am not sure how ready it is for production use.

There's also LegacyBar but also I couldn't find a sample with MVVMCross.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe LegacyBar has been used with MvvmCross - so that certainly could be an option for you.

Alternatively, another available option is to add data-binding support to the activities and/or fragments in Sherlock.

For activities, MvvmCross adapts activities into data-binding using a couple of small layers of code to add:

1. lifecyle events
2. a data-binding context

This code is described in [MVVMCross for android - how to do binding in code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16724278/mvvmcross-for-android-how-to-do-binding-in-code)

If you follow the two steps from the 'Additionally' section in that question, then that should enable you to create an `MvxSherlockActivity`

---

For fragments, there's no detailed existing answer here on SO, but the process is basically the same two steps with:

1. an event layer like - https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/v3/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid.Fragging/Fragments/EventSource/MvxEventSourceFragment.cs
2. a data-binding layer like - https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/v3/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid.Fragging/Fragments/MvxFragment.cs

This same code should allow someone to create an `MvxFooFragment` from any `FooFragment`

Comment: This is great - you literally use that code, and replace fragmentactivity with sherlockactivity and it works! easy

Comment: in case anyone is interested, you can also utilise the MvvmCross.Dialog with ABS, you just need to do as above but instead of  inheriting from SherlockActivity, you need to create a new class (i called it SherlockDialogActivity) and inherit from sherlocklistactivity, and copy the source code from dialogactivity

Comment: @benpage all sounds excellent - please do blog and or gist.github.com share it :)