# Cannot resolve current top activity while showing viewmodel using mvvmcross

Tags: c#, android, android-fragments, mvvmcross, presenter

I'm implementing a custom presenter in my Mvvmcross application. What I wanted to accomplish is: regular navigation and fragment navigation.

In my main activity, I managed to embed several fragment views based on this example: https://github.com/i486dx400/MultiRegionPresenter

while the fragments are working, I also wanted to show regular activities, that aren't hosted as a fragment. Therefor I extended this presenter as shown in this snippet: https://gist.github.com/JelleDamen/7003702

**The problem/bug:**
When I show this second activity, it gets shown. But when I go back to the previous view (which is the host) and re-open the same activity again, it doesn't get shown. The output log says: "mvx:Warning: Cannot Resolve current top activity"

What am I doing wrong, or what should I do, to inform the framework what activity is the current top activity?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is going wrong?

The line of trace you have provided is shown from:

```
    protected virtual void Show(Intent intent)
    {
        var activity = Activity;
        if (activity == null)
        {
            MvxTrace.Warning("Cannot Resolve current top activity");
            return;
        }
        activity.StartActivity(intent);
    }
```

in https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/v3/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid/Views/MvxAndroidViewPresenter.cs

So it would appear that when Show is called, then there is no current MvvmCross Activity shown.

... and looking at https://github.com/i486dx400/MultiRegionPresenter/blob/master/RegionEx.Droid/MainActivity.cs it does appear this is true - the main activity in the app is **not** adapted for MvvmCross, but is instead just a normal FragmentActivity.

> what should an app do to inform the framework what activity is the current top activity?

MvvmCross normally tracks the "top activity" by intercepting Activity lifecycle events - specifically the Activity created, started, restarted, resumed and destroyed events. These are shown in the lifecycle diagram  in http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

MvvmCross:

- hooks into these events via the MvxActivityAdapter in https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/v3/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid/Views/MvxActivityAdapter.cs
- these hooks call the extension methods in https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/v3/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid/Views/MvxActivityViewExtensions.cs
- these extension methods inform the lifecycle monitor about the lifecycle changes - see https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/v3/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid/Views/MvxAndroidLifeTimeMonitor.cs#L35 -

All the built-in MvvmCross Activity types - MvxActivity, MvxFragmentActivity, etc - call these "automatically". These adaptions can be extended to other Activity types using steps like those described in [ActionBarSherlock with latest MVVMCross](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16801728/actionbarsherlock-with-latest-mvvmcross), or your app can manually call some of these hooks if it prefers.

---

Personal opinion: I think you'd be better off not following https://github.com/i486dx400/MultiRegionPresenter too closely. The code in `OnCreate` in https://github.com/i486dx400/MultiRegionPresenter/blob/master/RegionEx.Droid/MainActivity.cs seems to try to `Start` the app every time that MainActivity is created - which can, of course, happen multiple times during the lifecycle of each app.

Instead, read that sample and others like http://motzcod.es/post/60427389481/effective-navigation-in-xamarin-android-part-1, https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/Xam.NavDrawer/tree/master/Mvx and http://enginecore.blogspot.ro/2013/06/more-dynamic-android-fragments-with.html - then implement something that suits your navigation needs.

Comment: Thanks Stuart! My mainactivity was indeed a regular fragmentactivity. And the app does get started every time I rotate this activity, which is not desirable. 

I will look into the links you suggested, thanks.