# is there a way to use the facebook sdk with MvvmCross Xamarin.Android?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, mvvmcross, facebook-sdk-4.x

I know that what I am about to ask is quite similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19397283/cannot-resolve-current-top-activity-while-showing-viewmodel-using-mvvmcross), but it's not the same case... Namely, I am making an MvvmCross Xamarin native app and have implemented Facebook's sdk. But upon returning to my Activity after a successful login and calling the command of my VM which navigates to the next Activity nothing happens and by examining the output I found the following: "mvx [Warning] Cannot Resolve current top activity". I guess it is due to the com.facebook.FacebookActivity not being of the MvxActivity variety.

So my question is:
is there a way to use the facebook sdk with MvvmCross?

Thanks.

Comment: are you using it just to login in your app or something else? because if it's to login I know how to use it

Comment: @fmaccaroni it's just to log in