# MvvmCross for MonoDroid - How to bind to Menu Item Click event

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I have an MvvmCross PCL and a related MonoDroid UI project (pattern copied from following Stuart Lodge's excellent N+1 video series). I want to bind the click of an Action Bar menu item to an ICommand in my ViewModel. I've seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16724278/mvvmcross-for-android-how-to-do-binding-in-code) but an IMenuItem doesn't appear to have a suitable property to bind to. I'm aware of the SetOnMenuItemClickListener method but (and this is no doubt my lack of understanding) don't know how to leverage this to bind a System.Windows.Input.ICommand to it.

Also, if this is possible, can it be done in the OnCreateOptionsMenu method of the MvxView as this provides a handle to the Action Bar menu itself?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think you can bind it, as the ActionBar is something that is loaded outside of the XML view. Also it does not expose any C# type of events for clicks on items as they are populated from a menu xml file. However you could in your `SetOnMenuItemClickListener` execute commands when a `MenuItem` is clicked. You can simply execute a command like this:

```
ViewModel.MyAwesomeCommand.Execute();
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I don't see how I could use the .Execute() method though as my ViewModel constructor uses the IoC pattern, e.g.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I don't see how I could use the .Execute() method though as my ViewModel constructor uses the IoC pattern, e.g. public NewJobViewModel(IDataService dataService, IMvxPictureChooserTask pictureChooserTask, IMvxFileStore fileStore) and I can't make my Command method static as I'd then need an instance of my ViewModel to call the methods in Model. Or am I missing something?!

Comment: Please ignore my above comment as I've since found the Mvx.Resolve method which looks like the approach I need to take. I've hit problems with this also but probably down to my lack of understanding. I've **[posted another question relating to this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17426862/mvvmcross-failed-to-resolve-type-for-viewmodel)**

Comment: Actually, ignore my point above, I didn't realise that MvvmCross provided the ViewModel property which you just cast to the relevant type and thus providing you with direct access to the ViewModel's properties and methods: `((NewJobViewModel)ViewModel).MyAwesomeCommand.Execute(null);`