# MvvmCross - Failed to resolve type for ViewModel

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin, mvvmcross

This is related to [another question I posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17407576/mvvmcross-for-monodroid-how-to-bind-to-menu-item-click-event) but probably warrants its own.

I need to be able to execute a Command in my ViewModel from its related Android View and specifically when an Action Bar menu item is clicked. Therefore, first of all I need access to the instance of the ViewModel.

Firstly I tried the following line of code in the  `OnCreateOptionsMenu(IMenu menu)` method of the **View**:

```
NewJobViewModel newJobViewModel = Mvx.Resolve<NewJobViewModel>();
```

However, this caused the error: `"UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: Cirrious.CrossCore.Exceptions.MvxException: Failed to resolve type MyProject.Core.ViewModels.NewJobViewModel"`

I then tried this instead:

```
[Activity]
public class NewJobView : MvxActivity {
    private NewJobViewModel _newJobViewModel;

    public NewJobViewModel NewJobViewModel {
        get { return _newJobViewModel; }
        set { _newJobViewModel = value; }
    }

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.NewJobView);
        this.NewJobViewModel = Mvx.Resolve<NewJobViewModel>();
    }
}
```

...which didn't help.

However, adding the following to `Apps.cs` cured the error but caused other issues as it clearly hadn't given me the same instance of the ViewModel that the MvvmCross framework must have already initialised in the background(?):

```
public override void Initialize() {
    CreatableTypes()
        .EndingWith("NewJobViewModel")
        .AsTypes()
        .RegisterAsSingleton();
}
```

I clearly misunderstand some of the architecture and what's happening in the background (so I apologise if this is a basic question) but can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MvvmCross automatically wires up your `View` and `ViewModel` for you.

This happens automatically during the call to `base.OnCreate(bundle);`

If you want to access your `ViewModel` within your View you can do this using the `ViewModel` property.

However, since the `ViewModel` property is defined in a shared base class, it is of type `IMvxViewModel`

To get a typed `ViewModel` you can simply cast it to your specific type - e.g.

```
 var myTypedView = (MyTypedViewModel)ViewModel;
```

You definitely don't want to create a new viewmodel (which is what `Mvx.Resolve<NewJobViewModel>()` tries to do) - instead you just want access to the current one.

Comment: Thanks for that Stuart, it solved my problem and I've now managed to wire up the click event of the Action Bar to a command in my ViewModel. PS: I've found your N+1 video series a fantastic way to learn MvvmCross. Keep up the great work :-) Graham.

Comment: But what about scenarios such as a tab view, with a HomeViewModel that has some child view models, one for each tab. Do you new up each of the child view models, and pass all dependencies to the HomeViewModel? Why not use Mvx.Resolve in the HomeViewModel constructor?