# How to do control binding in code for MonoDroid?

Tags: xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I am facing an issue with control binding in code in mono droid. I have an activity inheriting from MvxActivity and I saw some article to perform data binding in code using CreateBindingSet(). Can someone tell me what assembly reference I need on my monodroid project to get this method? If possible, can someone help me out with a sample example as well?

I am using V3 of MvvmCross.

Thanks
Amit

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does MvvmCross allow binding of ViewModel properties to controls created on the fly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17713770/does-mvvmcross-allow-binding-of-viewmodel-properties-to-controls-created-on-the)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have a `using Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.BindingContext;` and then you should be able to use `Bind()` on stuff.

Take a look at the [DialogExamples Tutorial](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross-Tutorials/blob/master/DialogExamples/DialogExamples.Droid/Views/FirstView.cs) in the [MvvmCross-Tutorial repository](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross-Tutorials).

Binding is pretty simple, you need to create a binding set first:

```
var bSet = this.CreateBindingSet<TView, TViewModel>
```

Then you can use that to Bind UI objects:

```
bSet.Bind(myTextView)
    .For(v => v.Text) //View Property
    .To(vm => vm.Stuff) //ViewModel Property
```

There is also a lot more information on bindings in [the Bindings Page in the Wiki](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/wiki/Databinding).