# Binding viewModel property to view property in MvvmCross

Tags: mvvmcross

I'm using MvvmCross and SherlockActionBar. My problem is that I need to make item in SherlockActionBar dissapear depending on value of some ViewModel property.

Item in the actionBar have property IsVisible but unfortunately it doesn't have a setter (you need to set visibility by item.SetVisible(boolValue) ) so I decided to make my own property ItemVisible in View.cs (binding it to the ViewModel-property) which will on change call item.SetVisible.

I've searched how to do in code bindings and [found this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16724278/mvvmcross-for-android-how-to-do-binding-in-code).

So I bind ItemVisible View property to ViewModelProperty but it never stepped into ItemVisible setter. Of course I raise RaiseAllPropertyChanged in viewModel after ViewModelProperty could be changed. I've looked into [mvvmcross bindings](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/Databinding) but I didn't find answer for my problem. What am I doing wrong?

```
    public class SomeView : BaseActionBarActivity {
    private IMenuItem _item ;

    private bool ItemVisible
    {
        get { return _item.IsVisible; }
        set { _item.SetVisible(value); }
    }

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        SetTheme(Resource.Style.Theme_Sherlock);
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.SomeView);

        var set = this.CreateBindingSet<SomeView, SomeViewModel>();
        set.Bind(this).For(p => p.ItemVisible).To(e => e.ViewModelProperty);
        set.Apply();
    }

    public override bool OnCreateOptionsMenu(Xamarin.ActionbarSherlockBinding.Views.IMenu menu)
    {
        SupportMenuInflater.Inflate(Resource.Menu.SomeMenu, menu);

        _item = menu.FindItem(Resource.Id.xmlMenuResource);
    }}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd guess this is due to the `private` in `private bool ItemVisible` - MvvmCross needs to use reflection to call this member and it's hard to do this on `private` members due to CLR security restrictions.

Try:

```
public bool ItemVisible
{
    get { return _item.IsVisible; }
    set { _item.SetVisible(value); }
}
```

This topic is also covered a little in N=18 and N=28 in http://mvvmcross.blogspot.co.uk/ (and was also covered in my NDC London talk on https://speakerdeck.com/cirrious/data-bind-everything but I'm afraid that hasn't been video recorded yet!)